# Flask: Address already in use, regardless of port

Tags: python, flask, jupyter-notebook, hydrogen

so I'm pretty new to Flask and i've been following a tutorial but I have been getting a strange problem. I have the following code, a python3 script, launched in atom with the hydrogen package enabled and jupyter. I have the virtual environment running in the background in a terminal.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So obviously the script is very basic and it's just used to see if i can connect to localhost, however when running it (through Hydrogen) I get the following error:

---

- Serving Flask app '**main**'
- Debug mode: on
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
  Press CTRL+C to quit
- Restarting with stat
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in 
  app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 977, in launch_instance
  app.initialize(argv)
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 110, in inner
  return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 666, in initialize
  self.init_sockets()
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 307, in init_sockets
  self.shell_port = self._bind_socket(self.shell_socket, self.shell_port)
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 244, in _bind_socket
  return self._try_bind_socket(s, port)
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 220, in _try_bind_socket
  s.bind("tcp://%s:%i" % (self.ip, port))
  File "/home/uses12/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 232, in bind
  super().bind(addr)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 568, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 28, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
  zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use

---

Upon looking online, a possible solution was to specify the port in the app. parameters, however no matter what port I specify it ALWAYS says that the address is already in use, leading me to believe that there is some deeper issue. I've done a check to see what services are using those ports and it's always just two instances of python3, I guess because Flask is set to debug. I'm completely lost. Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Comment: The issue isn't with your Flask server but with ZeroMQ, which seems to be used by Jupyter. Can't help you any further, my Python days are well behind me.